# Is their any books where the collection quotation of Milarepa are available?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

Is their any books  where the  collection quotation of Milarepa are available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Hundred Thousand Songs of Milarepa](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1570624763)

I have a copy and it is a pretty awesome collection of traditional poems ascribed to the historical Milarepa. Most are very insightful, if you know how to interpret them.

[image: The Hundred Thousand Songs of Milarepa]

Comment: thanks  a lots  @Andrei Volkov

Answer (score 1):

In French: “Milarépa - Oeuvres complètes, La vie, Les cent mille chants” translated from Tibetan by Marie-José Lamothe, Fayard, ISBN 978-2-213-62897-4

As far as I know, it’s not available in English.

[image]

Comment: oks thanks for this @still Just james but i didn't know french

Comment: I thought that would be the case, but I was only able to find his complete works in French when I was looking for it myself.